# How can I cast an object in one line of code and call a function?

Tags: c#, casting

In C#, how can I cast an object to another object type so that I can call a function that only the cast object has? I am wanting to do this in one line of code.

Here is my code where I create a new object of the cast type:

```
if (_attributes[i] is DynamicPropertyAttribute)
{
    var attribute = _attributes[i] as DynamicPropertyAttribute;
    attribute.Compile();
}
```

I am trying to do the above in one line of code.

Here is what I have:

```
if (_attributes[i] is DynamicPropertyAttribute)
{
    (DynamicPropertyAttribute)_attributes[i].Compile();
}
```

Here is the error:

> 'System.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'Compile' and no
>   extension method 'Compile' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Attribute' could be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap brackets around the cast.

```
((DynamicPropertyAttribute)_attributes[i]).Compile();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using c# 6, you can make it even simpler with “?.” operator, sometimes called the Safe Navigation Operator.

```
//no need for the if check anymore

(_attributes[i] as DynamicPropertyAttribute)?.Compile();
```

Comment: It is worth highlighting it is `C# 6.0` feature/syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to cast and call the function in 1 line:

```
if (_attributes[i] is DynamicPropertyAttribute)
{
    (_attributes[i] as DynamicPropertyAttribute).Compile();
}
```

However if you are using C# 6.0 then you can use the Null-conditional operator **`?.`** and avoid using the explicit null checking, making the code easier to read.

```
(_attributes[i] as DynamicPropertyAttribute)?.Compile();
```

Example from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx:

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null 
Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null
```